# Insert into MySQL Python not writing any data

Tags: python, mysql

I have created the following table in MySQL

```
create table DT (Date varchar(20), Time varchar(20))
```

I am using the following Python code to insert into MySQL.  I am not getting any error nor is the date and time is getting written into MySQL.

```
import mysql.connector
from datetime import datetime

conn = mysql.connector.connect(host = 'localhost', database = 'mydatabase', user = 'root', password = '')
cursor = conn.cursor()
i = datetime.now()
xdate = i.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
xtime = i.strftime('%H-%M-%S')
sqql = 'insert into DT (Date, Time) values (%s,%s);'
cursor.execute(sqql, xdate, xtime)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

However when I directly do the insert in MySQL it works..

```
insert into DT (Date, Time) values ('2017-02-06', '19-54-36');
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not passing the query parameters correctly, put them into a tuple, replace:

```
cursor.execute(sqql, xdate, xtime)
```

with:

```
cursor.execute(sqql, (xdate, xtime))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this example](http://www.mikusa.com/python-mysql-docs/query.html) and [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html), the method `cursor.execute()` takes a string query as first parameter, and the second parameter is a tuple or a dictionary that contains the values of that query. So you should call the method this way:

```
cursor.execute(sqql, (xdate, xtime))
```

In case you are using `xdate` and `xtime` just in this invocation, you can even simplify this call by:

```
cursor.execute(sqql, (i.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), i.strftime('%H-%M-%S')))
```

In addition, you can also use a dictionary in order to improve the readability of the code:

```
sqql = 'insert into DT (Date, Time) values (%(xdate)s, %(xtime)s);'
cursor.execute(sqql, {'xdate': `xdate`, 'xtime`: xtime})
```